# SQL 2016 & SQL Server Data Tools 2015 Errors at deployment not in english

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

Can I switch the Errors back in English without changing the Regional Settings? Since the errors at current language are not use and changing the settings at the Machine that I deploy from is not an option. One more thing that I notice only the Errors at deployment are not in English.

Comment: The messages have nothing to do with the regional settings. You probably installed a non-English version of SSDT

Comment: I have installed the English version. And even so there is not Bulgarian version to download. I have tried that it tie to the regional setting but I can't touch them at the server I have to deploy since it's a client's one and there are other applications running from it.

Comment: I have checked again SSDT  the ENU in add/remove programs.